# Как сделать бордер градиентом, кторый будел лежать на картинке

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, может я не до конца понятно описал проблему в название вопроса. Не знаю как сделать такой бордер как на скрине выше что бы он был и градиентом (насколько я понял), и что бы ещё и на картинку вылазил. Рылся в инете на эту тему, не чего не нашел. Можно ли сделать такой вот бордер вообще?

```css
/*Team*/
.w-team {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin: 36px 0;
}

.w-team p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.w-team p::before, .w-team p::after {
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    width: 8%;
}

.w-team .h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
}

/*teame page*/
.flex-t {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-t span {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.flex-t p {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
}

.line {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f34739;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    width: 180px;
    margin: auto;
}

.team-p {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.olivia {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    margin-left: 55px;
}
```

```html
          <div class="team-p">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="adriana flex-t">
                         <div class="col-md-7">
                          <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/7/831ecfa5bcdc2b6f55c5167737c38f08-full.png" alt="">
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-5">
                            <h2 class="h2">Adriana</h2>
                            <span>Senior Graphic Designer<div class="line"></div></span>
                            <p>She is the graphic designer with <br> 3 years of professional <br> experience.</p>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                        <div class="olivia flex-t">
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/7/8728fe0d983492e614946d328db6b005-full.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h2 class="h2">Olivia</h2>
                                <span>Art Director<div class="line"></div></span>
                                <p>She is the art director with <br> 8 years of professional experience.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вашем месте, я бы не верстал это так, как вы себе представили, т.е. это все разные блоки, а не один большой. Примерно так следовало бы:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.article {
  min-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.article__picture {
  background: #cca3ff;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.article__text {
  background: #e5d0ff;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.article__picture:after,
.article__text:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.article__text:after {
  border-color: #000;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  border-left: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}

.article:nth-child(even) .article__picture {
  order: 1;
}

.article:nth-child(even) .article__picture:after,
.article:nth-child(even) .article__text:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}

.article:nth-child(even) .article__text:after {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="block">
  <article class="article">
    <div class="article__picture"></div>
    <div class="article__text"></div>
  </article>
  <article class="article">
    <div class="article__picture"></div>
    <div class="article__text"></div>
  </article>
  <article class="article">
    <div class="article__picture"></div>
    <div class="article__text"></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо всё теперь получилось

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я вижу, только два цвета, черный и белый, их можно сделать так:

```css
.wrap {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
background-color: red;
}
.flex {
margin: 20px;
height: 300px;
flex-grow: 1;
border: 5px solid white; /*Добавляем бордер 2ум элементам*/
}
.flex1 {
margin-right: 0;
border-right: none;/*У левого убираем правый*/
}
.flex2 {
border-color: black;
border-left: none;/*У правого - левый*/
margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="flex flex1"></div>
<div class="flex flex2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Идея такая(через linear-gradient и псевдо-элементы), только настрой размеры в `linear-gradient` в зависимости от `.col-md-7`:

```css
/*Team*/

.w-team {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 36px 0;
}

.w-team p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.w-team p::before,
.w-team p::after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  width: 8%;
}

.w-team .h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}


/*teame page*/

.flex-t {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-t:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.flex-t:nth-child(odd):before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, black 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, black 2px), linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, black 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, white 2px);
  background-position: top, right, bottom, left;
  background-size: 100% 2px, 2px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.flex-t:nth-child(even):before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, white 2px), linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, black 2px);
  background-position: top, right, bottom, left;
  background-size: 100% 2px, 2px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.flex-t span {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.flex-t p {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.line {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f34739;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
}

.team-p {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.olivia {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-left: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="team-p">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="adriana flex-t">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/7/831ecfa5bcdc2b6f55c5167737c38f08-full.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <h2 class="h2">Adriana</h2>
          <span>Senior Graphic Designer<div class="line"></div></span>
          <p>She is the graphic designer with
            <br> 3 years of professional
            <br> experience.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="olivia flex-t">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/2/7/8728fe0d983492e614946d328db6b005-full.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2 class="h2">Olivia</h2>
          <span>Art Director<div class="line"></div></span>
          <p>She is the art director with
            <br> 8 years of professional experience.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Градиент, думаю, сами подберете

```
 .flex-t{
  position: relative;
}
.flex-t:after{
  content: '';
  background: #eee;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxaeJw